# What is meant by authoring in workflow Foundation

Tags: workflow-foundation

I need to what is meant by authoring in workflow foundation and what are it's types.

Answer (score 0):

Authoring basically means creating new or modifying existing worklfows. There are two basic types, the sequential and the state machine workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found out. Authoring is mode of writing the workflows.
They are three types.

1. Code based
2. No Code and XOML based
3. Some code based.